# my post request using nodejs express to mongodb database doesn't work strangely?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, http-post, postman

I am trying to post data to the sever to be save into mongodb. Notice get request is working right but I couldnt post any data to mongodb database.

The main code:

```
// Tools to be used in the web development
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(bodyParser.json());


Genre = require('./models/genre.js');
Book = require('./models/book.js');



let conn = mongoose.connection;
conn.openUri('mongodb://localhost/bookstore');

conn.on('error', err => console.error('mongodb connection error', 
err));
conn.on('connected', () => console.info(`Connected to mongodb`));
conn.on('disconnected', () => console.info('Disconnected from 
mongodb'));


// Routing to specific pages:
app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.send('Hello World');
});

app.get('/api/genres', function(req , res){
Genre.getGenres(function(err, genres){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(genres);
})
});

app.post('/api/genres', function(req , res){
var genre = req.body;
Genre.addGenre(genre, function(err, genre){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(genre);
})
});

app.get('/api/books', function(req , res){
Book.getBooks(function(err, books){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(books);
})
});

app.get('/api/books/:_id', function(req , res){
Book.getBookById(req.params._id, function(err, book){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(book);
})
});

//Specify the listening port
app.listen(3666);
//Display the url on the termianl
console.log('Server Running On http://localhost:3666');
```

Genres

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var genreSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name:{
    type: String,
    requires: true
},
create_date:{
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
});

var Genre = module.exports = mongoose.model('Genre', genreSchema);

module.exports.getGenres = function(callback, limit){
Genre.find(callback).limit(limit);

}

//add genre
module.exports.addGenre = function(genre, callback){
Genre.create(callback);

}
```

I post using postman app and once I press post I receive nothing and nothing be added to the database

Postman Procedure

[Postman Procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMxvC.png)

and The database before and after the post procedure remain the same

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9mLB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
module.exports.addGenre = function(genre, callback){
   Genre.create(genre, callback); // genre is object to be added, { name: "Name" } for example
}
```